# My footer is double the size than it should be

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add HTML CSS to my Microsoft Sharepoint page. I started learning HTML CSS 2 weeks ago so this is new to me. My script makes my footer contain like 30% of the page as i scroll down. How can i fix this. I want the footer maybe to be as much size as the header.

```css
<style>
  body {
   margin: 0;
  }
  p {
   font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
  }
  .header {
   background-color: skyblue;
   height: 100px;
   text-align: center;
   color: #4f889f;
   padding: 1px;
  }
                .container{ 
                          width:100%;
                          position: relative;
                           }
  .container div {
   padding: 1%;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   min-height: 700px;
                        height:100%;
  }
                  
  .left-col, .right-col {
   background-color: #f4f4f4;
   width: 25%;
   float: left;
  }
  .center-col {
   width: 50%;
   float: left;
  }
  .footer {
   clear: both;
   font-family: 'Amatica SC', cursive;
   background-color: skyblue;
   text-align: center;
   height: 50px;
   padding-top: 10px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
  }
 </style>
```

```html
<div class="header">
 <h1>The 3 Column Layout</h1>
</div>
<div class="container">
 <div class="left-col">
      <img src="Cyber.jpg" width="200" height=150"/>
             <p><p>Morbi volutpat turpis pretium </p>

 
 </div>
 <div class="center-col">
  <h2>Center</h2>
  <p>Integer interdum finibus tempor.</p>
 </div>
 <div class="right-col">
  <img src="Random.jpg" width="200" height=150"/>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
 &copy; All Rights Reserved.
</div>
</body>
```

[image: This is how it looks]

Comment: Your code seems to work for me, run the snippet. What environment are you running this in?

Comment: You may have other css properties causing conflict here, as it works perfectly for me (see: https://codepen.io/04kurisu/pen/jOOJWxr).

I suggest inspecting your footer (right click > Inspect Element) and seeing if there's anything other than your own style trying to inject css into the footer, that could be the issue.

Comment: @Laif I am sorry I do not understand what an enviroment means but if it helps i am running the code in a Microsoft Sharepoint page.

Comment: It means what browser, is it under another project,etc..

Comment: @Laif I am using IE but it seems to be the same in Chrome too. Its not under any project

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to be working fine, but the height of the div might be causing you this issue that you are seeing. So even though the footer doesn't actually go down that far, there is a lot of white space beneath it due to the size of the page, so wherever you are running this project, it is showing the blue instead.

A fix would be to increase the height of your `.container div`. Since as soon as you change the min-height or the height, it changes where the footer is and the white space beneath it.

You could also make the footer stick to the bottom. Add this to the `.footer`:

```
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
```

This will keep the footer in the bottom of the page.

Let me know if these don't resolve your problem. Side note, make sure to surround your "height" inline styles with quotations for the `<img>` tags in your html. I noticed that they were missing the left-most quotation. Your html: `height=150"/>`. Preferred: `height="150"/>`. This isn't causing your issue but thought i'd mention it nonetheless